# Cant connect to apache from anywhere but local host?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am really sorry, but I could not find any thing relatable. I am attempting to set up a an Apache server for a friend in florida, and from the computer that it is hosted on, you can connect with localhost:2056 and its address on her LAN, but you cant connect from the IP 72.******:2056. The port is open on her router, and says it is directing to it (192.168.0.11)... I really would like help on this, I am really confused, I have done this before but never have had this kind of problem.

[Here is the httpd.cfg](http://pastebin.com/JjH65gq2) (Link to pastebin)

Again, super sorry if this is a bad question, but GoDaddy took down our website, and lost most of the data, switching to a dedicated machine we use for everything else, and now for hosting the site.

Comment: did you check her firewall settings to make sure that the machine isn't blocking that port?

Comment: As you said, Apache2 is perfectly working. This is a port forwarding/firewall problem. Port forwarding tables and firewalls settings might be useful ;)

Comment: If you claim that the router is forwarding to the internal port but you still not getting connected, you might want to check if the server is accepting connection from outside of locahost. Try connecting to it from another machine within the local area network. If you can't connect from within the LAN,  your server's firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the port from port 80 on your Apache server.  Just instruct the router to port forward from external ip:2056 to internal ip:80.

EDIT: Added external: and internal: